# Get results of For-Each arrays and display in a table with column headers one line per results

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am trying to get a list of files and a count of the number of rows in each file displayed in a table consisting of two columns, Name and Lines.

I have tried using format table but I don't think the problem is with the format of the table and more to do with my results being separate results.  See below

```
#Get a list of files in the filepath location
$files = Get-ChildItem $filepath 

$files | ForEach-Object { $_ ; $_ | Get-Content | Measure-Object -Line}  | Format-Table Name,Lines
```

## Expected results

Name Lines

File A
9

File B
89

## Actual Results

Name                                  Lines

File A
                                      9
File B
                                      89

Comment: you are correct - you are outputting two items. [*grin*] i would build a custom object in your `ForEach-Object` segment and output that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach how to make a custom object like this: [Using PowerShell's Calculated Properties](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/01/19/using-powershell-calculated-properties.aspx):

```
$files | Select-Object -Property @{ N = 'Name' ; E = { $_.Name} }, 
    @{ N = 'Lines'; E = { ($_ | Get-Content | Measure-Object -Line).Lines } }
```

> ```
> Name                      Lines
> ----                      -----
> dotNetEnumClass.ps1         232
> DotNetVersions.ps1            9
> dotNETversionTable.ps1       64
> ```

Comment: How are you  getting you results to format with alignment, my results are jagged where I want them to appear like a table with the headers lining up with the results

Comment: Sorry, I don't grasp your jagged format issue. Maybe in ISE: `Tools` => `Options…` check `Font Family` and make sure that it's a fixed-size font. However, if your file names are combined both Latin and double-width characters (such as CJK) then I have no solution…

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would make a custom object like this, instead of outputting two different kinds of objects.

```
$files | ForEach-Object { 
  $lines = $_ | Get-Content | Measure-Object -Line
  [pscustomobject]@{name = $_.name
                   lines = $lines.lines}
} 


name     lines
----     -----
rof.ps1     11
rof.ps1~     7
wai.ps1      2
wai.ps1~     1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this also works! Can you tell me how I can now format the result to appear as yours does, my numbers appear jagged against the line of my file names.

Comment: It should be the same.  Maybe you have a typo.

Comment: It works for me.  Are you in powershell 5?  Not that the code won't work on subdirectories.

Comment: Yes I am in 5, I am a complete beginner so this is literally my first piece of code, is there anything I should have done in the settings?